# Loops with return statements in a recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I have written a recursive function. Here's the pseudocode for that :

```
    public recFunction(Node node) {
        for(int i=0; i<node.childCount(); i++){
            Node child = node.child(i);
            if(child.satisfies condition)
                return true;
            else
                return recFunction (child)
        }
        return false
    }
```

Now, the node has a structure like:

```
               a
              /  \
             b    c
            / \  / \
           d  e  f  g
```

here, the condition is true only in case of "f". But when the function moves to d and e and they return false, the function doesn't even bother to move to "c". What is the reason behind this. I have always been a little foggy about recursive functions especially when they include loops with return statements. Could someone explain what happens in a case such as this?

Comment: That's no pseudocode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `for` loop is written as if it is supposed to iterate through all the node's children, but it always returns on the first iteration.

```
if (child.satisfies condition)
    return true;
else
    return recFunction (child);
```

If you want to look through all the children until you get a match, you might try this:

```
if (child.satisfies condition)
    return true;
else if (recFunction(child))
    return true;
```

or more simply

```
if (child.satisfies condition || recFunction(child))
    return true;
```

Then it will be possible for your `for` loop to continue and look at other children until it finds a positive result.